# Python - Changing an element in one array changes an element in a completely different array

Tags: python

I am currently attempting to create a list of ranges for letters in my program. I have done this through having a temp variable 'censorRange' to grab the range for an instance, then appending that variable to a 'censors' variable to be returned at the end of the function.

The issue is that when I change the 'censorRange' variable it also changes elements in the 'censors' variable. As an example:
Initially, 'censorRange' = [10,15], and 'censors' = [[10,15]]. When I debug the program when 'censorRange' goes from '[10,15]' to '[17,23]' then 'censors' will also go to [[17,23]]. Then at the end of the program censors will give me [[17,23],[17,23]] instead of [[10,15],[17,23]].

Why does this occur, and how can I fix the problem? I have attached the code I have been using below. If you have any suggestions please do tell me, I have been getting frustrated over this for a while now. Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
censors = []
censorRange = [None, None]
for match in matches:
    if((censorRange[0] != None) and (censorRange[1] != None)
       and (match.span()[0] > censorRange[1])):
            if(not lettersBetween(text, censorRange[1], match.span()[0], 5)):
                censorRange[1] = match.span()[1]
                censors.pop()
                censors.append(censorRange)
                censorRange[1] = match.span()[1]
            else:
                censors.append(match.span())
                censorRange[0] = match.span()[0]
                censorRange[1] = match.span()[1]
    else:
        censors.append(match.span())
        censorRange[0] = match.span()[0]
        censorRange[1] = match.span()[1]
return censors
```

Comment: You add `censorRange` to `censors` at `censors.append(censorRange)`. If you alter `censorRange`, you'll see that change in `censors` as well. If you don't want that, you'll need to make a copy of the inner list before adding it to `censors`. A copy of the list isn't made when it's added to the other list. If you change a list in one place, it will effect that list wherever it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a list to another list, it does not automatically make a copy. If you want to do that, you have to explicitly state so:

```
censors.append(censorRange.copy())
```

Comment: Please do not answer a question that has already been voted to be closed. Your answer just re-hashes what's in the linked question. We get so many questions of this exact nature. It's best just to point them to the established answers once you have sufficient rep.

Comment: @Carcigenicate But his question is not on how to make a copy. His question is on the cause of the error..